# Metatheorems in Category Theory

Tags: category-theory

In Borceux and Bourn's book "Mal'cev, Protomodular, Homological and Semi-Abelian Categories", the authors introduce two similar metatheorems that are used throughout the book to greatly simplify many proofs. Contrary to the well-known metatheorems resulting from embedding theorems such as Freyd-Mitchell's or Barr's, which pose strict conditions to the categories they can be applied to, but then allow to transfer large amounts of statements to easier categories, these metatheorems pose strict conditions to the structure of the statements, but can be applied to very general types of categories (arbitrary categories for the first metatheorem, and pointed categories for the second).

For those who don't have immediate access to the book, here are both theorems:

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a statement of the form $\varphi \Rightarrow \psi$, where $\varphi$ and $\psi$ can be expressed as conjunctions of properties in the following list:

1. (just for pointed categories) some arrow is a zero arrow;
2. some finite diagram is commutative;
3. some morphism is a monomorphism;
4. some morphism is an isomorphism;
5. some finite diagram is a limit diagram
6. some arrow $f: A \to B$ factors (of course, uniquely) through some specified monomorphism $s: S \hookrightarrow B$.

If this statement $\mathcal{P}$ is valid in the category of (pointed) sets, it is valid in every (pointed) category.

The proof proceeds via the Yoneda embedding, and then asserts that each of the above statements is valid in a presheaf category iff it is valid pointwise (i.e. in $\mathbf{Set}$ or $\mathbf{Set}_*$ respectively).

My problem is though, that in the proof the demanded structure of the statement $\mathcal{P}$ (implication of conjunctions) is ignored. It is only mentioned that the Yoneda embedding "preserves and reflects all ingredients which appear in $\mathcal{P}$" (i.e. the items on the list), and that "... all the properties listed in our statement are valid in $[\mathcal{E}^\text{op}, \mathbf{Set}]$ precisely when they are valid pointwise in $\mathbf{Set}$."

Even more irritatingly, the authors note afterwards, that "the list of properties in our metatheorem is not exhaustive. A better way to express the metatheorem would have been to state it for Horn sentences and the "unique existential quantifier $\exists!$", but we do not want to enter those considerations here.".

More generally, I wonder why I can't find this metatheorem anywhere else, since it is so useful. Is there an alternative formulation, e.g. via the internal logic of categories, which I do not recognize as equivalent yet?

Thus my questions are the following:

- How does a complete proof of the metatheorem proceed?
- How does the "better way" noted above work? Is there another source that elaborates this?
- Is there a more systematic way to formulate the theorems?

Comment: I didn't know about this theorem. If I had just a single star to subscribe to an MSE thread, I would use it here. Can you please add a precise pointer to Bourceux-Bourn statement in the book (like the page or the tag)?

Comment: Oh, wait, I've heard something similar once: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0102087 I suspect Tibor draws from some precedent theorems and adapts it in model category theory.

Comment: Pointers:
Sure; the 0th chapter in the book is completely devoted to these theorems, which are Metatheorem 0.1.3 and 0.2.7 on pages 3 and 7.

Comment: About your reference by Tibor Beke:
At first this looks to me like a much more complex setting than just arbitrary or pointed categories. Which part of the paper reminds you of the metatheorems?

Comment: Sure it is. It just has the same flavour, and amybe draws from the same ideas (i.e., Tibor "homotopified" ideas and statements in Borceux-Bourn)?

Comment: @Fosco You can also find the same ideas in the Preliminaries of [these notes](http://www.math.yorku.ca/~tholen/HB07BournClementino.pdf).

Comment: That is less surprising, since these notes share one author with my reference. It is more or less literally the same.

Comment: It's understandably a bit frustrating, but the point is that a formal proof of such a theorem would add many pages and little insight. Could you clarify which aspect you're most troubled by, in the first question? Is the authors' claim that all these properties are preserved and reflected by Yoneda clear? Is it clear why this implies the theorem? They really have given a complete proof.

Comment: Regarding the "better way", as well as the "more systematic way", it should be to state a "Cartesian embedding theorem" which says that the Yoneda embedding for a finitely complete category preserves and reflects all statements in the internal logic appropriate to such categories. This is called Cartesian logic by Johnstone and the nLab and essentially consists of Horn clauses and unique existential quantification. Such theorems are rarely stated since people are usually interested in fancier structure, such as Barr's embedding theorem for regular categories and of course Freyd-Mitchell.

Comment: This paper of Palmgren gets the idea across, although it specifically prefers to avoid the complications around unique existential quantification by modifying traditional cartesian logic. I'm not actually sure of a good source for the traditional treatment, but I assume it can be found in the Elephant. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007206001229

Comment: To your first comment: What frustrates me is not why all these properties (1.-6.) are preserved and reflected by the Yoneda embedding and whatnot, but that in the proof the authors don't refer to the actual structure (implication between conjunctions of the properties 1-6) of the statement $\mathcal{P}$ that they transfer to Set. They don't show that statements with this structure can be transferred, as well as the "elementary" properties 1-6. Since the proof just talks about "ingredients in $\mathcal{P}$", why does it not hold for disjunctions? Why is negation not allowed?

Comment: To your second comment:
This is at least a new keyword I can search for, and looks promising. Thanks!

Comment: Concerning your objection that people don't state such theorems, since the context is too simple:
I've wondered for a long time why no textbook introduces internal logic early on. Then such a theorem would be a perfect fit, and makes many proofs so much easier...

Comment: To your third comment:
Thanks, this looks like the thing I want to read. As for the Elephant though: I have no way to access it, which is pretty annoying.